# Argument Error (aws_access_key_id) on running rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

getting `validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)`

When I am running `rails s` to run an app which I cloned from bitbucket.

I am not sure how can I Solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're local environment variables don't include the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key. Is this a repo you work on with others? Perhaps they can share with you the those variables that you need.